# GetMe of Telegram's bot not working, with servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets, bots, telegram

I've just studied Servlet and JSP to the University, and I'm now trying to make a bot in Telegram just because, reading around the web, the bots can be menaged just with get/post request. 
I don't know why, but I'm not finding any other question on the web about making bot with Servlet, and in my school didn't teach us how to send http request to a server located somewhere around the web (just localhost).
So, the question is: can I send a request to a server on the web? Specifically, can I send at least a "getMe request" with servlet?

My ide is Eclipse, and exactly this is wath I've done:

Code a jsp page, with a row like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getme()">Hi</button>
```

Then, code a js page, with some easy rows of code:

```
function getme(){

  var xhr = getXmlHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("GET", "https://api.telegram.org/mytoken/getMe, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        alert("ok");
        var try = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        alert(try);
    }
   }

   xhr.send();
}
```

This code is not working. The "ok" alert will be displayed, but the alert "try" not instead. 
Firefox's console just say me of an end of data in JSON parsing:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

So, I think the request just isn't making.
My question is: what can I do to send this very easy request? Host my client on web?

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Sorry for missing the initial greetings. I've just forgetted it. I'm trying to edit the post but I don't see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved!!!
The problem was that I had to put "bot" before of my token's bot.
So, the right string is:

https://api.telegram.org/"bot" + mytoken/getMe

Like wrote before, the response text was an html page, not a JSON data, so the JSON parse gave me an arror because it wasn't finding the right JSON string.

Thanks avyway everyone, for your attention to my post!

PS: Thanks a lot to Postman that let me know the right response of the request.